# i created a search component but it is'nt desplaying results, how should i fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have two components in my React application:

SearchAccount: This component allows users to search for user accounts by account number.
CreateAccount: This component enables users to create new accounts.
registerContext: this also incudes context provider.
The issue arises in the SearchAccount component when I try to display the search result. Even when providing a valid account number, the search result is null, and I receive the following

im using .find function

i have tried this:-
Checked that userData is being fetched correctly from the context.
Verified the search logic in the handleSearch function.
Ensured that userDataArray is correctly populated before performing the search.
Implemented error handling in the component to handle the case when searchResult is null

Comment: // Search for user data by account number
        const result = userDataArray.find(user => user.accountNumber === parseInt(searchInput));